# How to logout when my token is expired and unauthorized?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, local-storage, access-token, angular-promise

The below code is my service.js.How to log out when my token is expired and unauthorized? Do we need to set local storage? can someone help me or suggest me how can I achieve the result which I'm looking for.Thanks in Advance

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Authentication')

.factory('AuthenticationService', ['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var service = {};

        service.Login = function (callback) {
            //authenticate data http
            $http.post('http://117d8128.ngrok.io/api/authenticate')
                .then(function (response) {
                    callback(response);
                });

        };

        service.SetCredentials = function (username, password) {
            var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);
            $rootScope.globals = {
                currentUser: {
                    username: username,
                    authdata: authdata
                }
            };
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata;
            $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
        };

        service.ClearCredentials = function () {
            $rootScope.globals = {};
            $cookieStore.remove('globals');
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ';
        };

        return service;


}])

.factory('TokenService', ['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var service = {};

        service.SetToken = function (token) {

            $http.defaults.headers.common['auth-token'] = token;
            $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
        };
        return service;
}])

.factory('Base64', function () {


    var keyStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

    return {
        encode: function (input) {
            var output = "";
            var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
            var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
            var i = 0;

            do {
                chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

                enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
                enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
                enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
                enc4 = chr3 & 63;

                if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                    enc3 = enc4 = 64;
                } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                    enc4 = 64;
                }

                output = output +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc4);
                chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
                enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
            } while (i < input.length);

            return output;
        },

        decode: function (input) {
            var output = "";
            var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
            var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
            var i = 0;

            // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
            var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
            if (base64test.exec(input)) {
                window.alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
                    "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
                    "Expect errors in decoding.");
            }
            input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

            do {
                enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
                enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

                chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
                chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
                chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

                if (enc3 != 64) {
                    output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
                }
                if (enc4 != 64) {
                    output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
                }

                chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
                enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

            } while (i < input.length);

            return output;
        }
    };

});
```

This is my controller.js for Auth

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('Authentication')
.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 
'AuthenticationService', 'TokenService', '$http',
function ($scope, $rootScope, 
$location,AuthenticationService,TokenService,$http) {
    // login status
    AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.dataLoading = true;
        AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
        AuthenticationService.Login(function (response) {
            if (response.data.success) {

               TokenService.SetToken(response.data.token);
                $http.post('http://117d8128.ngrok.io/api/users')
                .then(function(response){
                   console.log(response);
                     $location.path('/');
                });


            } else {
                $scope.error = response.message;
                $scope.dataLoading = false;
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

the below is my home controller. here when the token is unauth it should log out.but its not logging out.can someone help me?

```
  'use strict';

  angular.module('Home')

  .controller('HomeController',
['$scope',
function ($scope,$http) {
    $http.post('http://117d8128.ngrok.io/api/users')
                .then(function(response){
                   console.log(response);
                     $location.path('/');
                });

}]);
```

the main controller

```
    'use strict';

   //  modules
    angular.module('Authentication', []);
   angular.module('Home', []);

 angular.module('HttpAuth', [
'Authentication',
'Home',
'ngRoute',
'ngCookies'
 ])

 .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html'
    })

    .when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/home.html'
    })

    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}])

 .run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http',
function ($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
    // keep user logged in after page refreshed
    $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
    if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + 
$rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; 
    }

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        // redirect to login page if not logged in
        if ($location.path() !== '/login' && !$rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once user is successfully logged in, then you can store token in localStorage.

```
  //Storing token in local Storage
    service.setToken(token){
    $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
}
```

On your main controller, on every request you can check whether token is present/expired.

```
//Getting token from local Storage
service.getToken(token){
return $window.localStorage.getItem(token);
}
if(service.getToken()){
  //Proceed in the application
}else{
 //logout & redirect to homepage/login page
}
```

This is the jist of it, you can modify above code according to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, mayank.Will try it out :)

Comment: sure, feel free to ping me on further doubts :)

Comment: mayank i used cookie storage instead of local storage. I'm using $cookieStore.get('globals'). Does this work? please check my main controller in the above code edited.Thanks

Comment: yup, it will work, but do remember to attach expiration dateTime to your cookie. :)

Comment: var x = new Date(),
    x.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
   

$cookies.put('Token',{
  expires: x
});

var cookie = $cookies.get('Token');
console.log(cookie);

Not working :(

Comment: I analysed your code: and found couple of things you need to change.Instead of `cookies`, use `cookieStore`. You can replace your code with the following code `$cookieStore.put('Token','asdf454asdf.asdfas45asdf.asdfas4d5f');
  var cookie = $cookieStore.get('Token');
 console.log('cookie value:: ' + cookie)`. Just append your token and expiration data to the code, and it will work fine :)

Comment: one more doubt.How can i retrieve my token value to other controllers. I'm using 3 apps. I want to retrieve the token value to another app controller. can we achieve that?

Comment: Yes, we can achieve that, create one main controller, that will be invoked on every controller. Inside your main controller you can test for user's login activities.

Comment: I have helped solving your problem, please accept my answer :)

Comment: you're welcome, please upvote and accept my answer. :)

Comment: i have done that. As im new to stackoverflow i need 15+ points to display you upvotes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056993/how-to-load-ui-route-after-logging-in-by-using-url-in-main-controller

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056993/how-to-load-ui-route-after-logging-in-by-using-url-in-main-controller 
mayank can you help me with the above one ! .Thanks :)

Comment: @ManojSai : It seems, question has been removed

Comment: @manyank when im logging into the page then my home.html is displaying the content from my controller.when i reload the page ts throuwing error as 404 not found. Any suggestion regarding this?

https://embed.plnkr.co/a1cmv8/

Comment: just check whether cookie is storing user data.

Comment: manyank this is just demo. Didn't integrate with the backend. It's dummy authentication. But i'm not able to get the data after page reload